# Should I use static_cast or INT64_C to assign 64-bit constant portably?

Tags: c++, static-cast, int64

Assigning a 64-bit constant as

```
int64_t foo = 0x1234LL;
```

is not portable, because `long long`  isn't necessarily `int64_t`. This post [Which initializer is appropriate for an int64_t?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13275136/252576) discusses use of `INT64_C()` macro from `<stdint.h>`, but isn't it also possible to use `static_cast` as

```
int64_t foo = static_cast<int64_t>(0x1234);
```

?

Which one should I prefer and why, or do both of them work well?

I have searched on the internet and on SO, but did not find any place where the `static_cast` option is explored. I have also done tests using `sizeof()` to confirm that it works in the simple cases.

Comment: Won't static cast do the wrong thing if the constant is bigger than 64 bits, without saying anything?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits by the C implementation limits header `<climits>`. The minimum limit on the minimum and maximum values for an object of type `long long` is given as:

```
LLONG_MIN   -9223372036854775807 // −(2^63 − 1)
LLONG_MAX   +9223372036854775807 // 2^63 − 1
```

This corresponds to a signed 64 bit integer. You cannot store such a range of values without at least 64 information bits.

So go ahead and use `0x1234LL`. In fact, you can just as much use no suffix, because the first of the following types that can fit the value will be chosen:

```
Suffix | Decimal constants | Octal or hexadecimal constant
-------|-------------------|------------------------------
none   | int               | int
       | long int          | unsigned int
       | long long int     | long int
       |                   | unsigned long int
       |                   | long long int
       |                   | unsigned long long int
...    | ...               | ...
```

Comment: Thanks. What if long long is more than 64-bits, say 128-bits? I fail to recall what the standard says. Does assigning a larger type to a smaller type have well-defined behavior? (Of course, I am considering the case where the value fits within 64-bits.)

Comment: @Deidara-senpai In this case, where the destination type is signed, the result will be undefined if you try and fit a larger integer value in the `int64_t`.

Comment: Well, yes, I am aware of that, but if the value fits within 64-bits, then is the result well-defined?

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Maybe I'm confused, but of course, assigning a value that would fit in 64 bits to an `int64_t` will be perfectly fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I always have trouble remembering these things from the standard.