# Comparing long long with 0

Tags: c++, c, long-integer

```
long long llIdx = foo();
if (llIdx > 0LL) // Can I use 0 here?
  ...
```

Is there any problem if I use `0` instead of `0LL` in above code?

When should I prefer `0LL` over `0`?

Comment: `long long` is a `signed` type. It makes no difference if you write `x > 0ll` or `x > 0`, because `0` is automatically promoted to a `long long`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275136/which-initializer-is-appropriate-for-an-int64-t

Comment: Actually, the "signedness" of `long long` doesn't matter for this specific case. If the comparison was `llIdx >= 0` (or `0LL`) it would, because that predicate would always be true for `unsigned long long`.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use a plain `0` here. The compiler would look at the type of each argument to `>` and promote the smaller one so that they are the same size.

Thus `llIdx > 0` and `llIdx > 0LL` are equivalent.

Comment: "The compiler would look at the type of each argument to `>` and promote the smaller one so that they are the same size." That's why I didn't put my comment as an answer. There is a bunch of special cases if the sign of both integers vary.

Comment: Didn't see your comment while I was typing :) I was just trying to answer the specific question with a little more than "yes". And I presume you meant "signedness", not "sign"

Comment: So when we should use `0LL` instead of `0`?

Comment: @Deqing: I can't come up with a good example where usual arithmetic conversion does something unexpected if one operand has value 0. Variadic arguments are one (e.g. `printf("%lld", 0LL);`), and `unsigned n; int i; ... long long l = 0LL + n + i;` (if `long long` covers the range of `unsigned int`, what it probably always does, this prevents promotion of `i` to `unsigned`).