# Initializing objects with macros for integer constants

Tags: c, macros, integer, c11

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
7.20.4 introduces **Macro integer constants** with:

> 1 The following function-like macros expand to integer constants
>   suitable for initializing objects that have integer types
>   corresponding to types defined in <stdint.h>. Each macro name
>   corresponds to a similar type name in 7.20.1.2 or 7.20.1.5.

I don't quite understand this paragraph.
The macros basically slap the appropriate suffix onto an unsuffixed number as in:

```
UINT64_C(0x123) => 0x123ULL
```

But if I wanted to initializes an uint64_t, I would just do:

```
uint64_t x = 0x123;
```

and I wouldn't bother with the suffix at all.

Why would I need these macros in initializations?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275136/which-initializer-is-appropriate-for-an-int64-t

Comment: I think these macros were introduced just to duct tape over the language defect which is that there are no integer literal suffix for the stdint.h types. Kind of like the format specifiers for printf in inttypes.h.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UINT64_C(0x123)` macro creates an immediate `unsigned long long` number so it can be used in variable argument functions for instance or intermediate computations without the need for casting into the `uint64_t` type, where it is important that this particular data type is used.

Example:

```
printf("%llu\n",UINT64_C(0x123));
```

is correct

```
printf("%llu\n",0x123);
```

is incorrect and is undefined behavior because data size is not correct, and `printf` typically does not know that.

When you use `uint64_t x = 0x123;`, there is an assignment and an implicit conversion, so no need to do this (and `printf("%llu\n",x);` is correct).

Another usage is in intermediate computations, as illustrated below:

```
uint32_t a = 0xFFFFFFFF;
uint64_t x = a + UINT64_C(0xFFFFFFFF);
```

will produce the full 64-bit sum, whereas

```
x = a + 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

will wrap within 32 bits because intermediate result uses the `uint32_t` type.

A difference between `UINT64_C(SOME_CONSTANT)` and `(uint64_t) SOME_CONSTANT` is that if the value is too large for `UINT64_C`, the first case will produce a constant with the specified value in a wider type, and the second will produce a value converted to the named type. What errors these can cause and whether the compiler will diagnose the problem may depend on context.

Answer (score 0):

With u64 you tell that you want 64-bit integer. Some platforms provide it by defining `unsigned long long`, others by `unsigned long`. If your values are to interoperate with functions that need this info (e.g. printf and pals), you should deal with this indirection in order to have flexible code. 
In your example (`uint64_t ex = 0x123;`) type has this information, no need to explicitly call the macro. But I assume you need all the 64-bit, if it exceeds `int` values, you should have the `UL` / `ULL` postfices. Example:

```
unsigned ex = 0x100000000U;
// warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
```

Comment: You're getting the warning because of the assignment, not because of the suffix. The suffixes never downcast. If you `printf("%u\n", 0x100000000U);`, you get a warning about having the wrong format string (not truncation).