# When should I use UINT32_C(), INT32_C(),... macros in C?

Tags: c, fixed-width, misra, uint32-t

I switched to fixed-length integer types in my projects mainly because they help me think about integer sizes more clearly when using them. Including them via `#include <inttypes.h>` also includes a bunch of other macros like the printing macros `PRIu32`, `PRIu64`,...

To assign a constant value to a fixed length variable I can use macros like `UINT32_C()` and `INT32_C()`. I started using them whenever I assigned a constant value.

This leads to code similar to this:

```
uint64_t i;
for (i = UINT64_C(0); i < UINT64_C(10); i++) { ... }
```

Now I saw several examples which did not care about that. One is the `stdbool.h` include file:

```
#define bool    _Bool
#define false   0
#define true    1
```

`bool` has a size of 1 byte on my machine, so it does not look like an `int`. But `0` and `1` should be integers which should be turned automatically into the right type by the compiler. If I would use that in my example the code would be much easier to read:

```
uint64_t i;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ... }
```

So when should I use the fixed length constant macros like `UINT32_C()` and when should I leave that work to the compiler(I'm using GCC)? What if I would write code in MISRA C?

Comment: Personally I shy away from using the fixed width types: not all compilers support them and the promotion rules with these types are practically non-existent - in my humble opinion a big oversight in the C standard. Upvote for the question though.

Comment: Interesting question, can't wait to see the answers

Comment: You might need them if `int` is narrower than 32 bits.

Comment: @Bathsheba With the stdint types, you get a whole lot less implicit promotion problems than with the native types. This is because they behave deterministically, instead of having an arbitrary size. So with the stdint types you can write code that works portably no matter promotions, while with the native types you get code that may or may not work. But to write portable code properly, it is mostly a matter about the programmer actually being aware of implicit promotions, regardless of the choice of types.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing objects with macros for integer constants](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40406394/initializing-objects-with-macros-for-integer-constants)

Comment: Another dup: [Which initializer is appropriate for an int64_t?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275136/which-initializer-is-appropriate-for-an-int64-t)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, you should use them when the type of the literal matters. There are two things to consider: the size and the signedness.

Regarding size:

An `int` type is guaranteed by the C standard values up to `32767`. Since you can't get an integer literal with a smaller type than `int`, all values smaller than `32767` should not need to use the macros. If you need larger values, then the type of the literal starts to matter and it is a good idea to use those macros.

Regarding signedness:

Integer literals with no suffix are usually of a signed type. This is potentially dangerous, as it can cause all manner of subtle bugs during implicit type promotion. For example `(my_uint8_t + 1) << 31` would cause an undefined behavior bug on a 32 bit system, while `(my_uint8_t + 1u) << 31` would not.

This is why MISRA has a rule stating that all integer literals should have an `u`/`U` suffix if the intention is to use unsigned types. So in my example above you could use `my_uint8_t + UINT32_C(1)` but you can as well use `1u`, which is perhaps the most readable. Either should be fine for MISRA.

---

As for why stdbool.h defines true/false to be 1/0, it is because the standard explicitly says so. Boolean conditions in C still use `int` type, and not `bool` type like in C++, for backwards compatibility reasons.

It is however considered good style to treat boolean conditions as if C had a true boolean type. MISRA-C:2012 has a whole set of rules regarding this concept, called *essentially boolean* type. This can give better type safety during static analysis and also prevent various bugs.

Comment: Integer size doesn't matter either. Integer literals will be of the smallest type that can hold the literal's value, or (`unsigned`) `int`, whichever greater.

Comment: ... to make the language more detailed: (my_uint8_t + 1)  can become a signed integer, and shifting it will make it a negative value.

Comment: @JayLee No, since `1` has a type too and it is `int`, which is a larger integer type than `uint8_t`, with higher conversion rank. See this for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 3):

It's for using smallish integer literals where the context won't result in the compiler casting it to the correct size.

I've worked on an embedded platform where `int` is 16 bits and `long` is 32 bits.  If you were trying to write portable code to work on platforms with either 16-bit or 32-bit `int` types, and wanted to pass a 32-bit "unsigned integer literal" to a variadic function, you'd need the cast:

```
#define BAUDRATE UINT32_C(38400)
printf("Set baudrate to %" PRIu32 "\n", BAUDRATE);
```

On the 16-bit platform, the cast creates `38400UL` and on the 32-bit platform just `38400U`.  Those will match the `PRIu32` macro of either `"lu"` or `"u"`.

I think that most compilers would generate identical code for `(uint32_t) X` as for `UINT32_C(X)` when `X` is an integer literal, but that might not have been the case with early compilers.